# What is the java preferred way of serving byte data without copying it

Tags: java, arrays, object, stream, byte

For my case I have a class that holds a large amount of byte data in a single array.You can say;

```
byte myData[];//myData.length = very large number
```

What will I do is I will provide data for other classes/user via this class. However each request is partially included in myData array. For a request, it has starting index and ending index. When a user wants this request, I need to return the following:

```
System.arrayCopy(myArray,startIndex , requestBuffer , endIndex , requestBuffer.length);
return requestBuffer;
```

What I want to ask is; is there anyway of doing this without copying data because it may cause me in trouble like out of memory exeption when requests are too many.

Comment: Make a wrapper around your array which lets the client see only a segment of it. If you make the class final, you'll enjoy almost native speed for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend on [Kuba Spatny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21259849/2187042), you can create an encapsulation object which serves the data from the main array without giving any opportunity to alter the underlying data.

An example of this would be as follows:

```
public class EncapsulatedData {
    private final byte[] data; //<-- only holds a reference to the byte array, no data is copied
    private final int start;
    private final int range;
    
    public EncapsulatedData(byte[] data, int start, int end){
        this.data=data;
        this.start=start;
        this.range=end-start;
        
        if (end>=data.length || start<0){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
    }
    
    public byte get(int index){
        if (index>range){
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        return data[index+start];
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        byte[] bigData=new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
        
        EncapsulatedData dataProvider=new EncapsulatedData(bigData,4,9);
        
        System.out.println(dataProvider.get(0)); //prints 4
        System.out.println(dataProvider.get(2)); //prints 6
        System.out.println(dataProvider.get(4)); //prints 8
        System.out.println(dataProvider.get(5)); //prints 9
    }
    
    
}
```

In my case start and end are inclusive and all values are zero-indexed as usual. If you wish for the data range you expose to be modifiable by the class receiving the encapsulated data you can add a `set(int index, byte value)` method

### Making an encapsulated range itself encapsulatable

If you find that you want to further break down the exposed range into sub ranges you can do this by making the encapsulated range itself encapsulatable. This is done just by adding a new constructor.

```
EncapsulatedData(EncapsulatedData encapsulateData, int start, int end){
    this.data=encapsulateData.data;
    this.start=encapsulateData.start+start;
    this.range=end-start;
    
    if (end>encapsulateData.range || start<0){
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
....
....
....
public static void main(String[] args){
    byte[] bigData=new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    
    EncapsulatedData dataProvider=new EncapsulatedData(bigData,4,9);
    
    EncapsulatedData dataProvider2=new EncapsulatedData(dataProvider,1,3);
    
    System.out.println(dataProvider2.get(0)); //prints 5

}
```

This new encapsulation still talks directly to the `byte[]` but behaves as if it is a sub encapsulation

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to create an immutable object that would hold the reference to your byte array and two integers - start and end index.

You then would pass said object instead of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#slice%28%29) class.

Comment: The functionality to wrap an existing array shows up in Java 7.

Comment: @SimonC - you're right, it's there at least in Java 6. I'll edit the answer.